# ValueError: Cannot reindex from a duplicate axis - pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, duplicates

I know this question has already been asked, but I am completely new to Python an iPython and I am not managing to figure out how to solve my problem by looking at someone else's example.

I am working on a dataset to do some basic network analysis. Among the various dataframes, the one causing me troubles is a .csv file (called primary_results) which looks like:

```
state,state_abbreviation,county,fips,party,candidate,votes,fraction_votes
Alabama,AL,Autauga,1001.0,Democrat,Bernie Sanders,544,0.182
Alabama,AL,Autauga,1001.0,Democrat,Hillary Clinton,2387,0.8
...
...
```

and another one (county_facts) whose indexes are:

```
fips,area_name,state_abbreviation,PST045214,PST040210,PST120214,POP010210,AGE135214,AGE295214,AGE775214,SEX255214,RHI125214,RHI225214,RHI325214,RHI425214,RHI525214,RHI625214,RHI725214,RHI825214,POP715213,POP645213,POP815213,EDU635213,EDU685213,VET605213,LFE305213,HSG010214,HSG445213,HSG096213,HSG495213,HSD410213,HSD310213,INC910213,INC110213,PVY020213,BZA010213,BZA110213,BZA115213,NES010213,SBO001207,SBO315207,SBO115207,SBO215207,SBO515207,SBO415207,SBO015207,MAN450207,WTN220207,RTN130207,RTN131207,AFN120207,BPS030214,LND110210,POP060210
```

and this is the code I am trying to run:

```
primary_results = pd.read_csv( '../2016-us-election/primary_results.csv' )
county_facts = pd.read_csv( '../2016-us-election/county_facts.csv' )
county_facts_dict = pd.read_csv( '../2016-us-election/county_facts_dictionary.csv' )    

primary_results.index = primary_results['fips']
del primary_results['fips']

county_facts.index = county_facts['fips']
del county_facts['fips']

county_facts_dict.index = county_facts_dict['column_name']
del county_facts_dict['column_name']

county_facts_results = county_facts.loc[sorted(list(set(primary_results.index))), : ]    

trump_results = primary_results[ primary_results[ 'candidate' ] == 'Donald Trump' ]
trump_results = trump_results.sort_index()
trump_results.loc[:, 'percent_high_school'] = county_facts_results.loc[:, 'EDU635213' ]
trump_results.loc[:, 'percent_bachelors'] = county_facts_results.loc[:, 'EDU685213' ]
```

As a result I get the "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" on the penultimate line of the code, but I cannot understand why (it does not seems to me like there is such an error in the dataframe).

Any suggestions?

Comment: it seems to me that using `loc` is superfluous here `trump_results[ 'percent_high_school'] = county_facts_results[ 'EDU635213' ]
trump_results[ 'percent_bachelors'] = county_facts_results[ 'EDU685213' ]` should just work

Comment: Nope, I tried that way but I keep getting the same error!

Comment: I think to help you first post raw data and code that recreates your dfs that lead to this error

Comment: Sorry EdChum, I edited my previous comment, I made a mistake in the syntax of the code which gave me the unhashable type error. Now that the code  is right, the error is still "cannot reindex".
Isn't the code I posted enough? should I post something else?

Comment: I think you need to still post raw data/link to your data and code that reproduces this, one thing to consider is whether your lhs or rhs indices are unique at all, I think you can call `trump_results.index.duplicated()` and so on to check if this is the case

Comment: It is a notebook borrowed from kaggle: [link](https://www.kaggle.com/mpoegel/d/benhamner/2016-us-election/i-love-the-poorly-educated/notebook) 
you can download the dataset by clicking on "2016 US election" and then "download".
(Btw I tried using the duplicated function and now it says that there is no 'EDU635213' index in the csv file).
Thank you so much for your time!