# Find an EXACT substring in a pandas text column gives ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to match an EXACT substring in a pandas text column. However, when that dataframe text column has duplicate entries I get: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.

I reviewed the following post to determine how to query rows, but it was mostly about 
matching a whole entry rather than a substring. 
[Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

The following post showed how to find a substring using a regex pattern, which is EXACTLY what I need to look for regex word boundaries and *what I am using below*. 
[How to filter rows containing a string pattern from a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975069/how-to-filter-rows-containing-a-string-pattern-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

I was able to get the code from the 2nd SO post above working except where I have duplicates in my 
Comments column. Note, entries 600 and 700 in the debug.txt file below are dupes which is fine. These dupes are expected, so how do I accommodate them?

The data file 'debug.txt' and hence the dataframe has 2 unique columns, so it's not a dataframe issue with duplicate column names per this post:
Source: [ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis using isin with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788061/valueerror-cannot-reindex-from-a-duplicate-axis-using-isin-with-pandas)

----- debug.txt -----

```
PKey, Comments
100,Bad damaged product need refund.
200,second item
300,a third item goes here
400,Outlier text
500,second item
600,item
700,item
```

---

My code is below. Any help you can provide solving the ValueError above would be appreciated.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

# Define params used below
fileHeader = True

dictB = {}

inputFile = open("debug.txt", 'r')

if fileHeader == True:
    inputFile.readline()

for line in inputFile:

    inputText = line.split(",")

    primaryKey = inputText[0]
    inputTexttoAnalyze = inputText[1]

    # Clean inputTexttoAnalyze and do other things...

    # NOTE: Very inefficient to add 1 row at a time to a Pandas DF. 
    # They suggest combining the data in some other variable (like my dictionary)
    # then copy it to the DF. 
    # Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715965/add-one-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe

    dictB[primaryKey] = inputTexttoAnalyze

inputFile.close()

# Below is a List of words that must produce an EXACT match to a *substring* within 
# the data frame Comments column. 
findList = ["damaged product", "item"]

print("\nResults should ONLY have", findList, "\n")


dfB = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dictB, orient='index').reset_index()
dfB.rename(columns={'index': 'PKey', 0: 'Comments'}, inplace=True)

for entry in findList:
    rgx = '({})'.format("".join(r'(\b%s\b)' % entry))

    # The following line gives the error: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. 
    # I DO have expected duplicate values in my input file.
    resultDFb = dfB.set_index('Comments').filter(regex=rgx, axis=0)
    for key in resultDFb['PKey']:
        print(entry, key)

# This SO post says to run .index.duplicated() to see duplicated results, but I # don't see any, which is odd since there ARE duplicate results.  
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250626/valueerror-cannot-reindex-from-a-duplicate-axis-pandas

print(dfB.index.duplicated())
```

---

Comment: the reason for the error is likely related to duplicate index items. i.e. the column Comments which you set as index has duplicates. and hence the error. I would say that filter can be safely used when the indexes(columns or index keys) are guaranteed to be unique. otherwise. df[series.str.contains(pattern)] is a safer option

Comment: The code below gave me the results I need, however I'm curious about your proposal as well. I tried to apply it to my data frame in the code above --> dfB[series.str.contains(pattern)]  but received an error "NameError: name 'series' is not defined". What goes in the "series"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem I see is that the header for `Comments` has a leading space in it (", Comment") which could be causing the problem in the DataFrame.

If I understood you correctly, you are trying to identify all the rows in the DataFrame where the Comments contain one of the values in `findList`

The following may work for you (after you remove the leading space from the `Comments` header).

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def check(s):
    for item in findList:
        if re.search(r'\b' + item + r'\b', s):
            return True
    return False


findList = ["damaged prod", "item"]

df = pd.read_csv("debug.txt")

df[df.Comments.apply(check)]

Out[9]: 
   PKey                          Comments
1   200                       second item
2   300            a third item goes here
4   500                       second item
5   600                              item
6   700                              item
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Using a regular expression will allow you to perform an exact match. I have edited the original suggestion and included the regular expression.